# no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<int>&'

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote a code for vector usage, to store the integer number on desired length of vector. i.e

```
std::vector<int>  * parameters;
parameters = new std::vector<int>(10);
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    parameters[x] = x;
```

but compilation gives error :

no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const std::vector&'
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `(*parameters)[x] = x;`, or don't use pointers

Comment: its my requirement to use pointer as class variable. and then it will initialize on constructor of class

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the requirements and they want this: `int* parameters = new int[10]`?

Answer (score 1):

You declare a pointer to a vector, and you dynamically create one filled with 10 elements. Just declare a vector with 10 elements and fill those:

```
std::vector<int> parameters(10);
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    parameters[x] = x;
```

If you insist on using a pointer to a vector, you have to dereference (using the `operator*`) the pointer before doing anything with it:

```
(*parameters)[x] = x;
```

Note that this pointer stuff is plain silly. `vector` already manages its own contents via pointers, and there is no reason to have yet another pointer to the entity managing that content.

Comment: @hmb that's just a silly requirement, it creates an extra level of indirection, for what benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making a pointer to a vector? Just use the vector itself.

```
std::vector<int> parameters(10);
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    parameters[x] = x;
```

Otherwise if you left it with as a pointer (which I would discourage) you would have to dereference it first

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    (*parameters)[x] = x;
```